#include files for https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/spi.html Pi5 C/C++ development
Referring to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/spi.html
Writing code to use the SPI API's on a Pi5(RP1).  The spec shows the basic Structs  for each SPI API.  Those structs contain additional structs and I cannot find the include files where they are defined.

Are these kernel SPI APIs supported on the RP1 chip at the present time ?
What/where are the include files for the additional structs ?

thanks Tom

Welcome. "Writing code to use the SPI API's on a Pi5(RP1)" -> That stuff is for developing kernel modules, probably not what you want.  So the includes will be in the kernel source, but the API is not available in userspace, there's no library to link to, etc.

One of the Pi Engineers helped out with this answer and suggestion.
And the later 'h file and tools used within the
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h  makes this investigation very simple.
Re: #include files for https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/spi.html Pi5 C/C++ development environment
Quote
Tue Jun 11, 2024 1:21 pm
It's always best to look at the docs appropriate for the kernel you're working with - 4.14 was released in 2017, although it has only just been dropped from the LTS support (Jan 2024).
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.6/driver-api/spi.html
The easiest way to find things in the kernel tree is to use https://elixir.bootlin.com/
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h is where the SPI structures are defined. Yes RP1 (and bcm2835 before it) use the standard APIs.

Two links were incomplete
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.6/driver-api/spi.html          https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h
